# Is it possible to unlock a phone with usb debugging disabled?

Tags: lock-screens, usb-debugging, 8.1-oreo

I forgot the password of my old phone and even taking it to experts told me that it turns out impossible to recover data or unlock the phone. The phone is an honor 10 with Android OS 8.1.
Is it really impossible to attempt to recover the data?

Comment: No, it's impossible except for social engineering/bruteforcing. how many digits pin/pattern/password?

Comment: If the phone is encrypted by default then the only realistic way is to break the password/pattern/PIN.

Comment: So the only way out is to break the 4 digit pattern......

Comment: [possible](https://youtu.be/U3crtm6HiTE) but requires goood portion of luck. gatekeeper will increase timeout for each wrong attempt (up to 1/1day after 140 attempts)